# PHP Проблема при работе с классом

Tags: php, ооп

Создаю класс `My_Class`, в нем хранится информация об авторизации. Логины и пароли нужно получать извне и записывать в массив `$authorization`.

```
class My_Class {
public $login;
public $password
public $authorization = array(
        "method" => "log.pas",
        "params" => array(
            "login" => $login,
            "password" => $password
        )
    );
}
```

Такой код выдает ошибку: `Constant expression contains invalid operations`
Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делается через конструктор или сеттер.

```
...
public $authorization = array();
public function __construct($login, $password)
{
    $this->login = $login;
    $this->password = $password;
    $this->authorization = array(
        "method" => "log.pas",
        "params" => array(
            "login" => $login,
            "password" => $password
        )
    );
}
...
```

Создаем экземпляр класса:

```
$myClass = new My_Class('login', 'password');
```

Ну и свойства класса лучше сделать `private` и получать доступ к ним через геттеры...